# Resample Series/DataFrame with frequency anchored to specific time

Tags: pandas

I have inhomogeneous ~secondly data with a time series index that looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = [pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,35,327000), pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,37,325000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,37,776000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,38,233000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,40,946000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,41,327000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,42,06000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,44,99000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,44,99000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,46,289000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,49,96000),pd.datetime(2012, 2, 5, 17,00,53,240000)]

inhomogeneous_secondish_series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(dates)), name='some_col', index=pd.DatetimeIndex(dates))
```

---

```
In [26]: inhomogeneous_secondish_series
Out[26]: 
2012-02-05 17:00:35.327000   -0.903398
2012-02-05 17:00:37.325000    0.535798
2012-02-05 17:00:37.776000    0.847231
2012-02-05 17:00:38.233000   -1.280244
2012-02-05 17:00:40.946000    1.330232
2012-02-05 17:00:41.327000    2.287555
2012-02-05 17:00:42.003072   -1.469432
2012-02-05 17:00:44.099000   -1.174953
2012-02-05 17:00:44.099000   -1.020135
2012-02-05 17:00:46.289000   -0.200043
2012-02-05 17:00:49.096000   -0.665699
2012-02-05 17:00:53.240000    0.748638
Name: some_col
```

Which I want to resample to say '5s'. Normally I would do:

```
In [28]: inhomogeneous_secondish_series.resample('5s')
```

This yields nicely resampled 5s data anchored to the 0th second; In the result each item in the index will be on a multiple of 5 seconds from the 0th second of a given minute:

```
2012-02-05 17:00:40   -0.200153
2012-02-05 17:00:45   -0.009347
2012-02-05 17:00:50   -0.432871
2012-02-05 17:00:55    0.748638
Freq: 5S
```

How would I instead have the resampled data anchored around the time of the **most recent** sample, so the index would look like:

```
...
2012-02-05 17:00:38.240000  (some correct resample value)
2012-02-05 17:00:43.240000  (some correct resample value)
2012-02-05 17:00:48.240000  (some correct resample value)
2012-02-05 17:00:53.240000  (some correct resample value)
Freq: 5S
```

I expect the answer probably lies in the loffset paramater for resample() but wondering if there is a more simple way than having to calculate the loffset prior to resampling. Would I have to look at the latest sample, figure out it's offset from the nearest normal 5s frequency and feed that into the loffset?

Comment: @hayden It's just the index that is shown. The other columns don't matter, this is about resampling and applies to the time series index. The question applies a time indexed Series as well.

Comment: @hayden You're right, it isn't exactly easy to set this up; at least it takes a few min or so of work to reproduce it which is annoying for anyone trying to answer. Wasn't thinking, my bad. Adding code for creating the case. Also was referring to the wrong frequency. Hopefully makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loffset` just changes the labels, without changing how your data is grouped into the new frequency. So using your example:

```
max_date = max(dates)
offset = timedelta(seconds=(max_date.second % 5)-5
                , microseconds=max_date.microsecond-1)
inhomogeneous_secondish_series.resample('5s', loffset=offset)
```

would give you:

```
2012-02-05 17:00:38.239999   -0.200153
2012-02-05 17:00:43.239999   -0.009347
2012-02-05 17:00:48.239999   -0.432871
2012-02-05 17:00:53.239999    0.748638
Freq: 5S
```

From what I understand, this is not what you want - the last value should be the mean of the two last values in the dataset, instead of just the last value.

To change how the frequencies are anchored, you can use `base`. However, because this needs to be an integer, so you should use an appropriate microsecond frequency like:

```
freq_base = (max_date.second % 5)*1000000 + max_date.microsecond
inhomogeneous_secondish_series.resample('5000000U', base=freq_base)
```